# Content missing after converting hash to XML using XML::Simple in Perl

Tags: xml, perl, hash

**Code:**

```
my $test = {
    'a' => {
        'disabled' => 'false',
        'options' => '%build_options',
        'mailStatus' => {}, 
        'dependencies' =>{                                                                
            'test' => {                                                                                                              
                    'platforms' => {},                                                                                                 
                    'name' => 'nightly-regressions',                                                                                    
                    'preRequisitePlatforms' => {},                                                                                                             
                    'dependType' => 'pass'
                    },
        },                                                               
        'Above' => 'false',
        'options' => {},
        'critical' => 'true',
    }
};
print XMLout($test, noattr=>1, KeepRoot=>1, RootName=>undef, NoEscape => 1);
```

When I run above code to convert hash to xml, one level of "test" was missing, the output xml I got was:

**Output:**

```
<a>
  <Above>false</Above>
  <critical>true</critical>
  <dependencies>
    <name>nightly-regressions</name>
    <dependType>pass</dependType>
    <platforms></platforms>
    <preRequisitePlatforms></preRequisitePlatforms>
  </dependencies>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <mailStatus></mailStatus>
  <options></options>
</a>
```

Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my code?

Comment: Any good reason for using `XML::Simple`? The [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple) yells at you _PLEASE DO NOT USE THIS MODULE IN NEW CODE_...

Comment: Does this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60404484/3710053 your question?

Comment: Don't use XML::Simple. Just don't!  It's a huge waste of time and source of problems. Why won't people believe a module's documentation that admonishes using the module because it's so broken?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing XML::Simple with the strict option:

```perl
use XML::Simple qw(:strict);
```

You will find that you're missing a value for the KeyAttr option:

```perl
print XMLout($test, noattr=>1, KeepRoot=>1, RootName=>undef, NoEscape=>1, KeyAttr=>[]);
```